Dapr: Azure Service Bus receiving messages not working
I've set up an OrderService (ASP.NET Core Web API) application, which needs to listen to messages published on the Azure Service Bus Topic by receiving them. I can successfully send messages to the topic (POST SendMessages which retrieves a JSON and sends it to the Service Bus Topic), but I'm not able to get a notification to actually receive the send items from the topic.
What am I doing wrong?
Servicebus.yaml:
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: servicebus-pubsub
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: pubsub.azure.servicebus
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: connectionString
    value: "Endpoint=sb://<<sbName>>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<<key>>"
  - name: topic
    value: "order-service-event"
  - name: subscriptionName
    value: "test"

Program.cs:
... 
var app = builder.Build();

// Dapr will send serialized event object vs. being raw CloudEvent
app.UseCloudEvents();

// needed for Dapr pub/sub routing
app.MapSubscribeHandler();

...

// Dapr subscription in [Topic] routes orders topic to this route
app.MapPost("/orders", [Topic("servicebus-pubsub", "order-service-event")] (dynamic order) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Subscriber received order: " + order);
    return Results.Ok(order);
});

app.Run();

public record Order([property: JsonPropertyName("id")] int id);

OrderController.cs:
namespace OrderService.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class OrderController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost(Name = "send-messages-provisioned")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendMessages()
        {
            var _client = new DaprClientBuilder().Build();
            var messages = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("messages.json"));

            foreach (var message in messages)
            {
                await _client.PublishEventAsync("servicebus-pubsub", "order-service-event", message);

                string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
                Console.WriteLine("Published Message: " + jsonString);
            }

            return Ok("Messages sent successfully!");
        }
    }
}


Check your servicebus.yaml to ensure the connectionString, topic, and subscriptionName are correct and match your Azure Service Bus setup. Also, verify that the servicebus-pubsub name in [Topic] matches the component name in your YAML file.

@SirraSneha: I've just double checked, this matches properly.

I created a sample ASP.NET Core Web API application, successfully sent messages through a post request, and received the messages from the topic without any issues.

Ensure your application is running with the Dapr sidecar and that it is correctly configured to manage the subscriptions.

I added builder.Services.AddDaprClient(); in program.cs to set up Dapr and enable Pub/Sub interaction.

Also added builder.Services.AddControllers().AddDapr(); to enable Dapr in the controllers.


My Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDaprClient();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddDapr();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCloudEvents();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapSubscribeHandler();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

OrderController.cs :
using Dapr.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OrderService.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("order")]
    public class OrderController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DaprClient _daprClient;

        public OrderController(DaprClient daprClient)
        {
            _daprClient = daprClient;
        }

        [HttpPost("send")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendMessage([FromBody] Order order)
        {
            try
            {
                await _daprClient.PublishEventAsync("servicebus-pubsub", "test", order);
                Console.WriteLine($"Published order: {JsonSerializer.Serialize(order)}");
                return Ok("Message sent successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error while sending message: {ex.Message}");
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
    public record Order(int Id, string ProductName, int Quantity);
}

Servicebus.yml:
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: servicebus-pubsub
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: pubsub.azure.servicebus
  version: v1
  metadata:
    - name: connectionString
      value: "Endpoint=sb://<servicebusname>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<access-key>"
    - name: topic
      value: "test"
    - name: subscriptionName
      value: "samplesub"

Here, I have sent below message to Azure Service Bus topic using post request.

I ran the following command to start the Dapr and can see the sent data.
dapr run --app-id orderservice --app-port 5000 --components-path ./components -- dotnet run


I successfully received the message in the Azure Service Bus topic as shown.

